# Extending classes and instantiation

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, application-design, red-black-tree

Let's suppose we have a RedBlack-Tree implementation which consists of 2 classes:

- `Tree` - holds the pointer to the `Node *root` of the tree and defines all operations over the tree (`Insert`, `Delete`, etc)
- `Node` - a data storage, which holds pointers to `Node *parent`, `Node *left`, `Node *right` nodes and `std::string key`.

The `Tree::Insert()` has the following implementation:

```
void Tree::Insert(const std::string &key)
{
    Node *z = new Node(key);
    // adding node logic
}
```

Now the task: every node has to store the time of its creation.

Limitations: the base tree implementation should be modified as less as possible and should contain details of specific extensions (so it should know nothing about the creation time property).

My thoughts: extending `NodeWithTime : Node` and adding `unsigned int creation_time` property.

Where I'm in stuck: how would we instantiate the node now?

Any proposals?

PS: it's neither a homework or a job task - I'm just learning c++ and data structures.

Comment: "extending" is Java terminology. In C++ you **derive** from a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively simple. First, the Node struct:

```
template<typename T> struct Node {
    Node(T t) : value(std::move(t)), time(RightNow()) {}
    T value;
    TimeType time;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
};
```

A quick helper `make_unique`:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args> std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args...)));
}
template<typename T> void Tree<T>::Insert(T key) {
    auto z = make_unique<Node<T>>(std::move(key));
    // insert
}
```

First, I fixed your crappy `new` and `delete` and replaced it with smart pointers. Then I also made your tree a template because who needs a tree that can only do one type? Then I swapped out your `const T&` with a `T` so that it might live with move-only types.

Then I just added a Time field and called RightNow() in the constructor. The exact TimeType and RightNow() you use depends on your needs and what exactly you mean by "time of it's creation". Are we talking about "6th July, 2013"? Or a very-high-resolution clock? In any case, these "creation time" details do not impact the tree.

Edit: Wait, you want to have one tree type where only some of the nodes know the creation time? Or just to alter the tree so that *all* the nodes know the creation time? I did #2, but for #1, you could indeed simply inherit from Node. To wit,

```
template<typename T> struct Node {
    Node(T t) : value(std::move(t)) {}
    T value;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
};
template<typename T> struct NodeWithTime : Node<T> {
    TimeType time;
    NodeWithTime(T t) : Node(std::move(t)), time(RightNow()) {}
};
template<typename T> void Tree<T>::insert(T t) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> nodeptr;
    if (IWantToStoreCreationTime)
        nodeptr = make_unique<NodeWithTime<T>>(std::move(t));
    else
        nodeptr = make_unique<Node>(std::move(t));
    // insert
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but feeling weird for reading how to build a rocket on the question about a skateboard :-) Now will have to go and read about things like `typename... Args` that I see for the first time :-S

Comment: @zerkms: The answer *is* about building a skateboard. It's just that the skateboard you suggest will fall apart the instant you stand on it and was painted with lead paint.

Comment: `if (IWantToStoreCreationTime)` --- that's what I wanted to avoid. The node should handle that not the tree. The tree should be unaware of what kind of data `Node` (or any its descendants) stores.

Comment: I find both of these implementations less than ideal. The first forces a creation time on all users of the tree class. The second will have a `static_cast` somewhere if the user does something like search for a node and then request its creation time, because the pointers of the `NodeWithTime<T>`s are just `Node<T>`s. The only reasonable solution I've found is to use the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) on the node class.

Comment: CRTPing the Node class won't do you any good at all. You still have the same problem- either you guarantee that all nodes store their time, or you have to check at run-time if a particular node does if you want to retrieve that information. If you make that choice at run-time, then the owner of the nodes- that is, the tree- has to make the choice.

Comment: @DeadMG I thought it was obvious, but you need to template the tree as well.